# Long query in Amazon Redshift never return

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am facing a weird problem when running long queries in Amazon Redshift (>30min). Such queries do not provide feedback upon completion, even though they are completed when looking through the Redshift console or querying the stv tables.

We tested this in SQL Workbench/J, which uses the JDBC driver and a Node.js application using a Javascript-only driver. In all cases, queries keep going forever and never complete, not even with an error.

Comment: Sounds like something to report to Amazon; you're certainly paying for the privilege. Though: is there any NAT or stateful firewall between you and the Redshift node? If so, that'd be my first suspect - connection tracking table timeout. You really want to enable TCP keepalives, if that's even possible in Redshift.

Comment: I spent an entire day with Amazon support trying to figure out what was wrong. The case was then moved to the Redshift team. The weird thing is that the problem is new. We used to be able to run long queries (1h+) without any problem. But now, anything longer than 20 minutes never return.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to add `?tcpKeepAlive=true` at the end of the connection string. I find it helpful in some long running queries.

The same goes for other TCP keep alive settings for your operating system.

For example, for Mac:

`sudo sysctl -w net.inet.tcp.always_keepalive=1`

You would probably also want to optimize your queries not to take too long time. There are many options for that, depends on your actual queries. But a quick improvement you can get with the new SSD based nodes: http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/01/23/amazon-redshift-ssd-node-type/

Comment: Keep-alives were indeed the source of the problem. We fixed the problem locally using the documentation found at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-firewall-guidance.html. However, we still had to activate it on our EC2 instances, even though the documentation says we shouldn't have to do this.

Comment: I have default setting enabled on my machine. cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time - 7200
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_intvl - 75
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_probes - 9. Still I observed error " Unable to send the query to backend" though I connect with tcpKeepAlive=true

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a problem with connection timing out.

If your query should return some rows (`SELECT`), maybe try to [UNLOAD](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html) result into S3 bucket?

```
UNLOAD ('
   YOUR LONG RUNNING SELECT HERE
')
TO 's3://some_bucket/some/path/to/files'
WITH CREDENTIALS AS 'aws_access_credentials'
```

Keep in mind, that this will create multiple files (at least one per node) and you will have to merge them into one.

Comment: I also thought about that, so I tried a simple table copy. For example "INSERT INTO table_copy SELECT * FROM table" on a large table works (the table is filled), but the query never completes. If it runs in a transaction, then nothing happen since the COMMIT statement will never get to be executed.